# JPA composite primary key

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, maven-2

I have the following classes in my JPA model (getters, setters, and irrelevant fields omitted):

```
@Entity @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Currency {

    @Id
    private Integer ix;
}

@Entity @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Product {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
}
```

I need to define a class `Price`, such that when the [DDL is generated from the classes](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/hbm2ddl-mojo.html), the primary key of the corresponding table is composed of the keys for `Product` and `Currency`. I've tried the following:

```
@Entity @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@IdClass(PricePK.class)
public class Price {

    @Id @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Product product;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Currency currency;
}

@Embeddable
public class PricePK implements Serializable {

    Integer product;        
    Integer currency;
}
```

But this generates the following for the `PRICE` table:

```
create table PRICE (
    currency_id int null,
    product_id int null,
    primary key (currency_id, product_id)
);
```

Notice that both `currency_id` and `product_id` are nullable, which causes the following error when I try to load the DDL into SQL Server

> Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'PRICE'

I don't understand why these are nullable, because in the domain model they are annotated 
`@ManyToOne(optional = false)`

The DDL is generated using the `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect` SQL dialect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently I created ManyToMany relation using Composite Primary key and annotation as bi directional `@OneToMany`. This code works flawless. Maybe it will help:

[Mapping ManyToMany with composite Primary key and Annotation:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405746/mapping-manytomany-with-composite-primary-key-and-annotation)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `@IdClass`, the `PricePK` class need not be marked with the `@Embeddable`
 annotation. An example is given in http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/SetIdClassforCompoundKey.htm

I tried your code removing the `@Embeddable` on `PricePK` class, and the price table generated in MYSQL database with not null fields.

Following is how you could use `@EmbeddedId` to achieve the required result:
(getters and setters omitted)

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Price {

    @EmbeddedId
    PricePK pricePk;
}

@Embeddable
public class PricePK implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Currency currency;
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it didn't make any difference

Comment: Would you like to try using the `@EmbeddedId` method?

Comment: It didn't work either unfortunately