# Hibernate,Primary key consist from auto generated id and foreign key as pk

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Welecome, i pretty new in hibernate and i have problem.
Above I insert code example.
 Order should consist 2 primary keys id(own.auto generated pk) and other pk(also as fk from Client table) id of client whose make order. Everything work fine except that when I have added `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` I
am geting above errrors:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by reflection setter of pl.pb.intern.test.model.Order.id
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectSetter.set(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component$ValueGenerationPlan.execute(Component.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.id.CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator.generate(CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:735)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:727)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:388)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cascadeOnUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:364)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultUpdateEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireUpdate(SessionImpl.java:786)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.update(SessionImpl.java:778)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.update(SessionImpl.java:774)
    at pl.pb.intern.test.dao.HibernateClientDAO.updateClient(HibernateClientDAO.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set long field pl.pb.intern.test.model.Order.id to org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper$2
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.set(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectSetter.set(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:139)
    ... 67 more
```

My entities:

```
  @Entity
    public class Client
    {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    int id;

    @OnetoMany(mappedBy="client", cascade=CascadeType.ALL , fetch=FetchType.EAGER,orphanRemoval=true)
    List<Order> orders
    //other fields


    }

    @Enitity
    public classs Order
    {
        @Id
         @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
         int id;

         @Id
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn( name="order_client_id",insertable=false, updatable=false)   
        Client client;

           public void setId(long id)
          {
           this.id=id
          }

          public login getId()
         {
           return this.id;
        }
     }



    }
```

I have reviewed hibernate docs and i did't find any contraindications against connection auto generated primary key and foreign key as pk. What am doing wrong in this example??

Answer (score 0):

On the composite primary key issue, see [JPA composite primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450780/jpa-composite-primary-key)

From the exception stack trace, it seems the method signatures of your `Order.getId()`/`Order.setId()` have the wrong signatures. According to JavaBean conventions, since `Order.id` is an `int`, `setId()` should take an `int` parameter and `getId()` should return an `int` accordingly. Or, you can change the type of `Order.id` to `long` since `getId()`/`setId()` already make use of `long`.

Also, you may wish to edit your code to fix the following typos and syntax errors:
Client.java: 
    - `@OnetoMany` supposed to be `@OneToMany`
    - Missing end-of-line semicolon on `List<Order> orders`
Order.java 
    - Missing end-of-line semicolon on `this.id = id` in `Order.setId`