# hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property

Tags: java, hibernate

Here is another case of this ERROR:

```
21:22:15,881 ERROR [SessionFactoryImpl] Error in named query: ch.software.gvs.TroubleNotification_DeviceType.byType org.hibernate.QueryException: 
could not resolve property: type of: ch.ildsoftware.gvs.TroubleNotification_DeviceType
[select d.id from ch.ildsoftware.gvs.TroubleNotification_DeviceType d where d.type = :type]
```

I have following setting:

queries.xml:

```
<named-query name="ch.ildsoftware.gvs.TroubleNotification_DeviceType.byType">
    <query>
    select t.id from TroubleNotification_DeviceType t where t.type = :type
    </query>        
</named-query>
```

TroubleNotification_DeviceType.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tblgwTroubleNotification_ADSTyp")
public class TroubleNotification_DeviceType implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private TroubleNotification id;
private DeviceType type;
private String createdBy;
private String createdDate;

public TroubleNotification_DeviceType() 
{}

public TroubleNotification_DeviceType(TroubleNotification id, DeviceType type) {
    this.id = id;
    this.type = type;
}

@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "IDgwTroubleNotification", nullable = false)
public TroubleNotification getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(TroubleNotification id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "ADSTypID", nullable = false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "GeraeteTypID", nullable = false)
public DeviceType getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(DeviceType type) {
    this.type = type;
}

@Column(name = "Created", nullable = false)
public String getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
}

public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

@Column(name = "CreatedDate", nullable = false)
public String getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}

public void setCreatedDate(String createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}
}
```

I suspect there might be something wrong with the @Column and @JoinColumn annotation. It's just that the column-name I join with, is from a view which aliases the column name.
But maybe something else is wrong. I'm rather new to this.

snippet out of DeviceType:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Integer id;
private String name;

    ....

@Id
@Column(name = "GeraeteTypID", nullable = false)
public Integer getId()
{
    return this.id;
}
```

In other classes the reference would be like this, and work well (yet the column name is identical):

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "GeraeteTypID", nullable = false)
public DeviceType getType()
{
    return this.type;
}
```

snippet out of an EJB:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<TroubleNotification> getTroubleNotificationByDeviceType(DeviceType aType)
{
    // first get all IDgwTroubleNotification for ADSTypID
    Query idSet = gvsData.createNamedQuery(
            TroubleNotification_DeviceType.class.getName() + ".byType");
    idSet.setParameter("type", aType);
    List<TroubleNotification> idSetResult = idSet.getResultList();

    final List<TroubleNotification> troubleNotificationResult = new ArrayList<TroubleNotification>();
    for (int i = 0; i <  idSetResult.size(); i++) {
        // get all Notification for IDgwTroubleNotification
        Query notificationById = gvsData.createNamedQuery(
                TroubleNotification.class.getName() + ".byId");
        notificationById.setParameter("id", idSetResult.get(i));
        troubleNotificationResult.add((TroubleNotification) notificationById.getResultList());
    }
    return troubleNotificationResult;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: try to add @Embaddable on DeviceType

Comment: it says: `AnnotationException: ch.software.gvs.DeviceType must not have @Id properties when used as an @EmbeddedId`, and without @ID in DeviceType the error `AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: ch.ildsoftware.gvs.DeviceType` comes. Changind @Id to @EmbeddedId brings `AnnotationException: java.lang.Integer has no persistent id property`

Comment: In the meantime, I changed the code quite a bit. There is following situation in the DB: `TroubleNotification <- TroubleNotificationDeviceType -> DeviceType`. I followed the advices of [link][http://planet.jboss.org/post/hibernate_many_to_many_revisited]. The query is different, but seems to be fine: `select tn from DeviceType dt join dt.troubleNotifications tn where dt.id = :id`. The new error in this constellation is `MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: tblgwTroubleNotification, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(IDgwTroubleNotification)]`.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that my DB mapping was not at all proper. I have an n:m relation, which doesn't seem like an easy one with hibernate. But this was very helpful:
[Hibernate Many-To-Many Revisited](http://planet.jboss.org/post/hibernate_many_to_many_revisited)

But that was still not solving the problem. And I discovered that I have composite primary keys, that the primary keys of two tables are mapped in the n:m table. Another not so easy setting. So I followed this thread: [Mapping ManyToMany with composite Primary key and Annotation:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405746/mapping-manytomany-with-composite-primary-key-and-annotation)

The configuration from the second link, together with an SQL statement according to the second strategy in the first link works.