# Hibernate xml mapping one key to two other tables

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got the 3 following tables:

```
    Table1:
    keyA; keyB; keyC; (primary key is A+B+C)

    Table2:
    keyA; keyC; (primary key is A+C)

    Table3:
    keyA; keyB; (primary key is A+B)
```

With hibernate xml mapping I want for my Table1 to be linked to both Table2 and Table3 using these keys. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

simply describe a link many to many between the table 2 and 3 by the jointable table 1.
cf this example: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405746/mapping-manytomany-with-composite-primary-key-and-annotation)

Answer (score 0):

Well in your first Table `Table1` you have `(primary key is A+B+C)`, and you are asking:

> With hibernate xml mapping I want for my `Table1` to be linked to both `Table2` and `Table3` using these keys. Can I do that?

Yes, you can do that, **but** your two other tables `Table2` and `Table3` must have all the keys/columns that represent the `Primary key` of `Table1`, so they must contain the three columns  `keyA, keyB and keyC` along with a `OneToMany` mapping between `Table1` and both `Table2` and `Table3`.