# How can I do this kind of relationship(composite key?) in Spring Data and Kotlin?

Tags: orm, kotlin, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, relationship

I want to model this:

[image]

I doubt that this is right:

```
@Entity data class(@OneToOne val group: Group, @OneToOne val subgroup: Subgroup)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's relating to JPA more than kotlin language. You can reference this: [Mapping ManyToMany with composite Primary key and Annotation:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405746/mapping-manytomany-with-composite-primary-key-and-annotation)